# Error During "Find & Merge Duplicate Contacts"

Tags: duplicate-contacts

We recently upgraded to 4.7.16 and immediately starting having problems when checking for duplicate records.

I set up a very basic merging test -- same last name and email, I've tried picking a very small group (100 contacts), and I always get the same error.

No matter what Matching Rule or whatever group I create (even if it has a couple contacts), I always get the error.

My technical skills are very limited, so I was just checking to see if anyone else has experienced this.

Thanks!

[image: Matching Rule]

[image: Error Message]

Answer (score 1):

The problem you are hitting may be the one that I think we recently provided a fix for here: https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/10442